# É possível criar um título para a tag "select" sem que ela faça parte das opções?

Tags: html, html-select

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a tag "select", se é possível que ela tenha um título visível sem que seja parte das opções?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode definir um `select`, tendo um primeiro `option` marcado como desabilitado e, ao mesmo tempo, selecionado.

Veja:

## Jeito mais simples

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Cars</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

## Removendo ao selecionar com Javascript

Quando você selecionar o `input`, você pode removê-lo também usando o evento `onmounsedown`.

Veja:

```html
 <select onmousedown="document.querySelector('#fake').remove()">
   <option disabled selected id="fake">Cars</option>
   <option>Volvo</option>
   <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

Observe que,  nesse último exemplo, adicionei um id no `option` para ficar mais fácil de achá-lo via `querySelector`.

## Removendo o primeiro item com CSS

Você também pode definir como no primeiro exemplo, porém adicionando um `display:none` no primeiro `option`.

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected style="display: none">Cars</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

## Bloqueando o submit caso não tenha selecionado uma opção desejada

Nesse último exemplo, eu recomendo a utilização de um `required` no seu `select`. Aí, os outros `option` teriam que ter algum valor em `value`, deixando somente o primeiro sem nada em `value`.

Veja:

```html
<form>
<select required>
  <option disabled selected style="display: none;" value="">Cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

**Observação**: Se quiser definir um CSS para o primeiro `option` para diferenciar dos outros, é possível. Porém nos testes que eu fiz só funcionou quando você clica em `select` (e não sei se funciona em outros navegadores).

Testado no Google Chrome:

```html
<select required>
        <option selected style="color: #555; background-color: #ddd">Cars</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes Bens</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Acho que isso é o mais próximo do que desejo, legal se desse para colocá-lo em hidden na list, será que tem como?

Comment: Essa 3º tá perfect, vlw...

Comment: @MagicHat olha o 4º exemplo. Essa daí é para o formulário não deixar o submit, se o cara não tiver selecionar um item válido. Sem Javascript

Comment: Massa , required...show.. Só é ruim pq, não é muito abrangente em termos de browsers.. Nesse ponto como o form terá de qualquer forma um tipo de validação, ai vou apelar pro js, para esse fim

Comment: O seu segundo código fica me dando um erro: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null"* - O erro não ocorre na primeira vez que você faz a seleção, mas ocorre da segunda em diante.

Comment: @VictorStafusa creio que isso seja por conta do elemento ter sido removido. Talvez realmente seja melhor usar as "outras opções"

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Fonte: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela atenção, mas desta forma o "select" começa com uma opção "Volvo", eu gostaria que fosse visível por exemplo "Cars" e nas opçãoes a marca, mas que "Cars"  não fosse uma opção.

Comment: A respota do @NilsonUeahara esta correta, o optgroup representa apenas um texto não selecionavel dentro de um select.

Comment: @joaopaulosantosalmeida mas eu acredito que não seja o que foi pedido na pergunta.